# scalac error: bad option: '-make:transitive' on mvn package via command line

Tags: scala, maven

Following http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html to setup a simple scala maven project.

I got a BUILD SUCCESS after setting up scala-archetype-simple:1.6 using **mvn archetype:generate**.

But when I **mvn package**, I get **[ERROR] scalac error: bad option: '-make:transitive'**

What might the issue be? How can I fix it?

Using Scala version 2.11.7

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I just removed `<arg>-make:transitive</arg>` from **pom.xml** and compilation worked.

Also you may need to add

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
<artifactId>specs2-junit_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
<version>2.4.16</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

to get test passed.

Comment: To clarify, you may need to add the following dependency:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-junit_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.16</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: I dont even have `make:transitive` in my pom

Comment: Thanks a lot boris.

Answer (score 9):

**With intellij**

I had to remove it from IntelliJ compiler config, as compilation was failing while running scalatests in intellij.

The `.idea/scala_compiler` config was as below,

```
cat .idea/scala_compiler.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ScalaCompilerConfiguration">
    <profile name="Maven 1" modules="log-service">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="-make:transitive" />
        <parameter value="-dependencyfile" />
        <parameter value="$PROJECT_DIR$/target/.scala_dependencies" />
      </parameters>
    </profile>
  </component>
</project>
```

I removed the `-make-transitive` parameter for compiler, restarted the intellij.

*I have no idea who/why added `-make:transitive` parameter to .idea config.*

Comment: Not able to see .idea/config .

Comment: there's no `.idea/config`. I probably mean to idea config. check `.idea/scala_compiler.xml`